# A simple route planner

Tags: android, maps, app

I use Waze for navigation and it only allows one stop, so two destinations.  I can live with that. But more importantly, I often want to visit about 5 to 10 places.

Is there an Android App (a Windows Application will work too) that will allow me to order them to minimize distance covered. Essentially a travelling salesman problem.

Since its not for work  I would prefer it free or cheap.

Comment: Hi. there is this free web app http://map.vroom-project.org/ that can be used for mapping and solving distance. You can pick a place as start/end and add other intermediate points. But commercial version is via https://verso-optim.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of options:

- Apart from my comment above suggesting you try out [Vroom](http://vroom-project.org/)
- Another one to explore is [Graphhopper](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper). It has an Android client that uses its web service. You can also try out the [web app](https://graphhopper.com/maps/).

Comment: The web app works.  So does Google Maps, but why feed them more information?  Its not routing, but I can shuffle them around myself.

Comment: For route optimization, I think you'd have to check the jspirit manual. Not done it myself.  See here for example: https://graphhopper.com/api/1/examples/#optimization  Also see https://discuss.graphhopper.com/